# If / Else statement - not working for admin role - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 4 different user roles in my Wordpress site + the extra administrator role.

I have a `<div>` that I would only like to display to "manager" user role.

The following code should be only aimed to "manager" user role. So if the user has a "manager" user role, they will see the notice in the `<p>` block that says : This is a premium feature. You must have premium capabilities to upload your banner

Else
If the user "is not" a "manager", they will have an option to upload a banner.

I have this code in place :

```
<?
if(current_user_can('manager')) { ?>    
    <div class="button-area">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
        <p class="banner-help-block-heading">UPLOAD BANNER</p>
        <p class="banner-help-block">This is a premium feature. You must have premium capabilities to upload your banner</p>
        <div class="upgrade-button">
            <a href="#" class="button-green-upgrade">Upgrade Account</a>
        </div>
    </div><?
        $manager = true;
    }
else { ?>
    <div class="button-area<?php echo ($banner)? ' elect-hide':''; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
        <a href="#" class="elect-banner-drag elect-btn elect-btn-info"><?php _e('Upload banner', 'elect'); ?></a>
        <p class="help-block"><?php _e('Upload a banner for your profile. Banner size is (825x300) pixel.', 'elect'); ?></p>
    </div><?php 
    $manager = false;
    } ?>

            </div>
```

It works great for all user roles including "manager", but If I see the page as an "administrator" , I see what the "manager" should see. I see the premium feature notice. But instead I should be able to upload a banner.

So what I am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't see `manager` parameter on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Comment: that is a user role, it could be anything .. it could be "musician"

Comment: "WordPress has six pre-defined roles: Super Admin, Administrator, Editor, Author, Contributor and Subscriber" http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities Did I miss something, or you're using some custom roles?

Comment: Yes, and apart from these predefined roles, you can create additional roles that fit the niche of the website you're creating .. it could be Musician, Drummer or a Guitarist if you wish .. if you're using Woocommerce and selling products, then you could have a role "seller" .. If you have an accounting business, you could add a "manager" or "accountant" role ..

Comment: Good to know, you said the above code works, how about adding administrator to the condition `if(current_user_can('manager') || current_user_can('manage_options'))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the user role(s) of the current logged in user you have to check the role on the current_user-object.

```
$user_roles = $current_user->roles; // Array
```

but it is always better to check for the user capabilities.

if you still want to check the role of a user, here is a function that i wrote, ... maybe it helps you

```
function mi_checkUserRole($role, $userid = null) {
    $user = null;
    if ( !empty($userid) ) {
        $user = new WP_User( $userid );
    } else {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user = $current_user;
    }
    if ( !empty($user) ) {
        return in_array($role, $user->roles);
    }
    return false;
}

// Example:
$isManager = mi_checkUserRole("manager");
```

Comment: add the function to the functions.php of your theme. Then you can check the users role by calling the function (like in the Example below the fucntion-code).